# How can I "join" rows with the same ID in pandas and add data as new columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which contains multiple rows for individual clients. There is a separate row for each product with all fields identical other than the item and amount column for a given reference.

**Example**

```
       name reference   item amount
    0  john      1234  chair     40
    1  john      1234  table     10
    2  john      1234  table     20
    2  john      1234   pole     10
    3  jane      9876  chair     15
    4  jane      9876   pole     30
```

**My Problem**

Each customer has an unknown amount of entries in the database (around 10 entries would be the maximum). I want to edit this dataframe to have entries with the same reference on the same row. The row need to also have extra columns added for 'item 2' and 'amount 2'.

**Example Output**

```
       name reference item 1 amount1 item2 amount2 item3 amount3 item4 amount4
    0  john      1234  chair      40 table      10 table      20  pole      10
    1  jane      9876  chair      15  pole      30   NaN     NaN   NaN     NaN
```

After reading the documentation and having a look for other similar questions, I can only find how to merge / aggregate the data which will not work in my scenario.

Is this possible in Pandas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's `unstack()` by tracking position using `groupby()`+`cumcount()`:

```
df['s']=df.groupby(['name','reference']).cumcount()+1
df=df.set_index(['s','name','reference']).unstack(0)
df.columns=[f"{x}{y}" for x,y in df.columns]
df=df.reset_index()
```

output of `df`:

```
   name reference   item1   item2   item3   item4   amount1     amount2     amount3     amount4
0   jane    9876    chair   pole    NaN     NaN     15.0        30.0        NaN         NaN
1   john    1234    chair   table   table   pole    40.0        10.0        20.0        10.0
```

Comment: Thank you for this! One question though, lets say my dataframe had hundreds of columns, would there be a way to write this without including every column header in the 'groupby' and 'set_index '?

Comment: @CalumMackenzie-Chambers actually that depends on your need....here we are grouping on `['name','reference']` for tracking position but if there are more column then yes you have to add in `set_index()` method